# How to continuously run the server.php in php socket

Tags: php, version, php-socket

The overall code works but the problem is I need to refresh the `server.php` every single time just to work the entire code. How am I going to make the server run continuously without the hassle of refreshing the `server.php`?

**Client.php**

```
<?php
$host    = "localhost";
$port    = 1024;
$message = "Hello Server";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to  server\n");  
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "<br>"."Reply From Server  :".$result;
// close socket
socket_close($socket) ?>
```

**Server.php**

```
<?php
// set some variables
$host = "localhost";
$port = 1024;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
// reverse client input and send back
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write  output\n");
// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: Which OS is being used here?

Comment: @dbf i used windows

Answer (score 0):

meta refresh. I know you can set the interval. even at a second or millisecond may cause latency maybe streaming as well for second option..dotnet has well written streaming classes.